# Window 10 R 4.2.1 DBI::dbGetQuery Error message text unavailable

Tags: r, windows, db2, odbc, r-dbi

I am using Window 10. I was using R 4.1.3. I have recently updated to R 4.2.1.
I was able to query from our DB2 database by using the following script.

```sql
con = DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                       Driver = "iSeries Access ODBC Driver",
                       System = "DBServer",
                       UID = "User",
                       PWD = "Password",
                       Port = 6016)
df = DBI::dbGetQuery(con, sql)
```

R 4.1.3 would correctly query the results. R 4.2.1 produces an Error.

*Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1655: HY000: [IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver][DB2 for i5/OS] - Error message text unavailable.  Message can not be translated successfully.
 'SELECT * FROM PRODDTA.F4211 FETCH FIRST 3 ROWS ONLY'*

Does any one have a solution to resolve this error?

Comment: Additional, i can validate the connection using...
DBI::dbCanConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                       Driver = "iSeries Access ODBC Driver",
                       System = "DBServer",
                       UID = "User",
                       PWD = "Password",
                       Port = 6016)
This produces a TRUE response.

Comment: You may need to update to the latest version + fixes for the i Access ODBC driver. Also check the CCSID on the i box, is it 65535

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by re-install the iSeries Access ODBC Driver via the ACS Windows App Pkg English (64bit) download.
https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/odbc-driver-ibm-i-access-client-solutions